# Vertically align SPAN with UL

Tags: html, css

I have the following HTML ([Example](http://plnkr.co/edit/7m6VHy6FRcROzY360HTH?p=preview)):

```
<span>Sign in with</span>
<ul>
  <li><a href="#"><i class="icon-facebook"></i></a></li>
  <li><a href="#"><i class="icon-twitter"></i></a></li>
</ul>
```

And the CSS:

```
span {
  display: inline-block;
  font-weight: bold;
  margin-right: 6px;
}

ul {
  display: inline-block;
  list-style: none;
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

ul li {
  display: inline-block;
  list-style: none;
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 4px;
}

ul li {
  font-size: 2.0rem;
}
```

I would like the SPAN to be vertically aligned with the Icons in the UL. But I am not able to do it even when applying padding to span.

Any idea on how to solve this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to vertically center text with CSS?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8865458/how-to-vertically-center-text-with-css)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add `vertical-align:middle` to your `<i>` elements:

```css
span {
  display: inline-block;
  font-weight: bold;
  margin-right: 6px;
}
ul {
  display: inline-block;
  list-style: none;
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
ul li {
  display: inline-block;
  list-style: none;
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 4px;
}
ul li {
  font-size: 2.0rem;
}
i[class^="icon-"] {
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<link href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/toastr.js/latest/css/toastr.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/2.3.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/3.2.1/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<span>Sign in with</span>
<ul>
  <li><a href="#"><i class="icon-facebook"></i></a>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#"><i class="icon-twitter"></i></a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

HTML:

```
 <p>Sign in with</p>
    <ul>           
         <li><a href="#"><i class="icon-facebook"></i></a></li>
         <li><a href="#"><i class="icon-twitter"></i></a></li>
     </ul>
```

Comment: now check the code. This is one of the way to make the text vertically aligned with the icons. :)

Answer (score 0):

try this,

```
span {
  display: inline-block;
  font-weight: bold;
  margin-right: 6px;
  vertical-align:middle; /* added */
}

ul {
  display: inline-block;
  list-style: none;
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  vertical-align:middle;  /* added */
}

ul li {
  display: inline-block;
  list-style: none;
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 4px;
}

ul li {
  font-size: 2.0rem;
}
```